# Copy text in tmux using putty

Tags: terminal, tmux, clipboard, putty

I am using putty0.76 to connect to server and I run tmux2.7. I need to copy bigger amount of text to my local clipboard with scrolling during selection. I do not have `xclip` or `pbcopy` installed and I can not install it. I also can not install `tmux-yank` package. Solution with `set -g terminal-overrides 'xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'` causes problems by randomly missing lines of output. How can I set up my system to be able to copy text from Putty to Windows?

Answer (score 2):

A really good question, I believe.

I used PuTTY practically since it's original release, but in recent years I've shifted my workflow to Windows Subsystem for Linux.  Since Linux distributions running under WSL can utilized the standard Linux OpenSSH client, my use of PuTTY has fallen to the wayside.

That said, I still have PuTTY installed on an older computer, so I dusted it off to see what I could come up with.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to come up with much in the way of a "pure PuTTY" solution that will allow you to capture more than one screen of text from Tmux running on the remote system to the Windows clipboard, but here are some possible suggestions.  Some of them may or may not fit your workflow; or they may give you additional ideas to try:

###### Option #1:  Shot-in-the-dark suggestions

That `terminal-overrides` was a good attempt.  If that gets you close, then I'd recommend trying to solve the "missing lines" problem there first.

Shot-in-the-dark things to try there would include a combination of setting `set -w alternate-screen off` and setting the PuTTY option *Disable switching to alternate terminal screen*.

You might find that one of those *combined* with the `terminal-overrides` prevents the lost text, but again, this is just a complete guess.  It's the first thing I'd try, however, if I was in your shoes; it's a quick exercise.

###### Option #2:  Ultimate silly-hacky workaround

I'm not sure just how much text you need to copy, but if you need just a few times more than will fit on screen, perhaps decrease your font size in PuTTY until it fits ...

I almost hate to suggest it, but it might be the easiest solution, as silly and "hacky" as it is.

###### Option #3:  Copy to Tmux buffer, retrieve via `plink` and pipe to Windows clipboard (`clip.exe`)

- In Tmux on the remote system, enter Copy Mode with <kbd>Prefix</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>
- Move to the selected text beginning (or end) with the arrow keys
- <kbd>Prefix</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to begin selection
- Move to the other end of the selected text with the arrow keys
- <kbd>Prefix</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to copy to the Tmux buffer
- In PowerShell on the local Windows system, run:

  ```
  path\to\plink <connection_info> "tmux show-buffer" | clip.exe
  ```

  This assumes you are using key authentication via Pageant for the connection, since it can't ask for a password.

  It connects to the remote system where Tmux has stored the text in its buffer (`buffer0` by default), retrieves it from the default buffer, and pipes it to Windows `clip.exe` to place it on the clipboard.

###### Option #4:  Local-client Tmux under WSL

My preferred option, of course.  Using this method you can create one seamless keybinding in Tmux that copies the text directly to the Windows clipboard.

All of this is one-time setup.  Once completed, you can activate it with a single Tmux keybinding:

- Install WSL with Ubuntu (or a different distribution, if you prefer)
- Tmux is installed by default in WSL's Ubuntu distribution
- Run `tmux` under WSL
- Connect to the remote system via the `ssh` command in Ubuntu
- Enter Tmux copy-mode with <kbd>Prefix</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>
- Move to the selected text beginning (or end) with the arrow keys
- <kbd>Prefix</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to begin selection
- Move to the other end of the selected text with the arrow keys
- <kbd>Prefix</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> to enter the Tmux prompt
- `send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "clip.exe`
- If that works, bind the previous command to a key via `~/.tmux.conf` so that you can copy text from Tmux to the Windows clipboard at will